# ExtJS 6 modern "CODE" package build Sass compiler error

Tags: extjs

Using Sencha Cmd v6.5.0.180
From workspace home

```
sencha generate package --type=CODE --framework=ext --toolkit=modern my-menu
cd packages/local/my-menu
sencha package build
```

This works fine, however when I add an extension of Ext.panel.Panel

```
Ext.define('My.menu.Header', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
....
```

I now get fashion/sass compilation errors.

Is there additional setup needed in the package.json to tell the app build where to find sass resources (I want to use 'theme-material') or should I be disabling sass compilation for a package build, or something else?

Output:

```
[INF] appending sass content to C:\app\src\main\webapp\x6\packages\local\app-menu\build\app-menu-all-debug.scss
[INF] appending sass content to C:\app\src\main\webapp\x6\packages\local\app-menu\build\app-menu-all-debug.scss
[INF] Building C:\app\src\main\webapp\x6\packages\local\app-menu\build\app-menu-all-debug.scss to C:\app\src\main\webapp\x6\packages\local\app-menu\build\resources\app-menu-all-debug.css
[LOG] Fashion build starting for C:\app\src\main\webapp\x6\packages\local\app-menu\build\app-menu-all-debug.scss
[ERR] unknown definition for mixin named box-shadow : C:/web/src/main/webapp/x6/ext/packages/core/sass/etc/recipes/color.scss:202
[ERR] unknown definition for mixin named text-shadow : C:/web/src/main/webapp/x6/ext/packages/core/sass/etc/recipes/color.scss:205
[LOG] Build error for C:\app\src\main\webapp\x6\packages\local\app-menu\build\app-menu-all-debug.scss
{ Error: Sass compilation encountered 2 error(s)
    at Object.raise (C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\export\Base.js:131:17)
    at Transpiler.transpile (C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\Transpiler.js:1549:21)
    at Context.convert (C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\Context.js:42:34)
    at C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\Builder.js:147:45
    at SassFile.fireReady (C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\SassFile.js:426:17)
    at C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\SassFile.js:398:28
    at SassFile.fireReady (C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\SassFile.js:426:17)
    at C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\SassFile.js:398:28
    at SassFile.fireReady (C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\SassFile.js:426:17)
    at C:\Cmd\6.5.0.180\js\node_modules\fashion\src\SassFile.js:398:28 '$isFashionError': true }
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 1
[ERR]   at o
[ERR] rg.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 8 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
```

Comment: Adding the package to app.json[requires] array, and extending the packages panel class in the main app did produce a successful build. Should I just not be trying to build with 'sencha package build'?